# IronPython and setuptools/ez_install

Tags: ironpython, setuptools

Our company has developed Python libraries to open and display data from files using our proprietary file format. The library only depends on numpy which has been ported to IronPython.

The setup.py for our internal distribution imports from setuptools but apparently this is not yet supported in IronPython. Searching the wirenet produces many references to a blog by Jeff Hardy that was written three years ago.

Can someone explain the relationship between setuptools, ez_install, and distutils?

Is there a way to distribute our library that is compatible with both CPython and IronPython.

Many thanks,

Kenny

Answer (score 1):

Distribute is a fork of setuptools that supports Python 3, among other things. ez_install is used to install setuptools/easy_install, and then easy_install can be used to install packages (although pip is better).

Three years ago IronPython was missing a lot of the pieces needed, like zlib (2.7.0) and zipimport (upcoming 2.7.2). I haven't checked in a while to see it works, though, but any changes now should be minor.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I'll be eagerly awaiting 2.7.2.